# firebase hosting of Angular2 app showing blank page

Tags: angular, firebase

I have developed an angular2 app. I run through procedure of firebase hosting. But it is showing a default page not my app.

Please help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After building your app with `ng build --prod`, it will create a `dist` folder with production files. While running `firebase init`, you will want to set your public directory to `dist` instead of using the default `public/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem. I redeployed the app several times and had always the same result, like in the picture above.

**Problem:**

If you do not choose `dist` as public directory and **if you later replace** the `index.html`. Then Firebase **overwrites** the `index.html` **in your project**.

**Solution:**

I solved this issue by just **replacing** the `index.html` with one from another project.

Next time follow these instructions:

https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/deploying-an-angular-app-to-firebase/

Answer (score 0):

First find out in which folder is your index.html file, make sure it's the index.html that you wrote, cause firebase might put a mock index.html in the 'public' folder and move your index.html in the 'dist' folder, it might also have another folder with the name of your app inside the 'dist' folder. So either copy your original index.html and put it in the 'public' folder in the place of the mock, or go in the firebase.json file and change the 'public' property to the name of the folder where your index.html file is:

```
 {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

OR

```
 {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "my-app",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Also check the base reference inside of your index.html file, if it's `<base href="/">` change it to the name of your app like `<base href="/my-app/">`  you can also use the command line to do it, just write: `ng build --prod --base-href /my-app/`